# How can I change in real-time filtered words in tweetstream (Python)?

Tags: python, twitter, real-time

I need to save in real-time to a database all tweets from the Twitter Streaming API, filtering them by out a certain list of words, of course. I've achieved it by using [tweetstream](https://bitbucket.org/runeh/tweetstream/src), defining the list *words* like this before calling FilterStream():

```
words = ["word1","two words","anotherWord"]
```

What I'd like to do, is to be able to add/change/remove any of those values, **without stoping the script**. To do so, I created a plain text file containing the words I want to be filtered out separated by a line break. Using this code I get the list *words* just perfectly:

```
file = open('words.txt','r')
words = file.read().split("\n")
```

I made those lines work when it starts, but I need it to do it every time it's going to check the stream. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could read an updated word list in one thread and process tweets in another one using `Queue` for communication.

#### Example:

Thread that reads tweets:

```
def read_tweets(q):
    words = q.get()
    while True:
        with tweetstream.FilterStream(..track=words,..) as stream:
             for tweet in stream: #NOTE:it requires special handling if it blocks
                 process(tweet)
                 try: words = q.get_nowait() # try to read a new word list
                 except Empty: pass
                 else: break # start new connection
```

Thread that reads words:

```
def read_words(q):
    words = None
    while True:
        with open('words.txt') as file:
            newwords = file.read().splitlines()
        if words != newwords:
           q.put(newwords)
           words = newwords
        time.sleep(1)
```

The main script could look like:

```
 q = Queue(1)
 t = Thread(target=read_tweets, args=(q,))
 t.daemon = True
 t.start()
 read_words(q)
```

Instead of polling you could use `inotify` or similar to monitor changes to the `'words.txt'` file.

Comment: That's amazing! It works great :D I might add a time-based function in order to not get banned because connections being closed and started to quickly. Thank you, really!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this will work:

```
def rebuild_wordlist(s):
    with open('words.txt','r') as f:
        return set(f.read().split('\n'))

def match(tweet):
    return any(w in tweet for w in words)

words, timestamp = rebuild_wordlist(), time.time()
stream = tweetstream.SampleStream("username", "password")
fstream = ifilter(match, stream)

for tweet in fstream:
    do_some_with_tweet(tweet)
    if time.time() > timestamp + 5.0:
        # refresh the wordlist every 5 seconds
        words, timestamp = rebuild_wordlist(), time.time()
```

The *words* set is a global that gets refreshed every few seconds while the filter is running.

Comment: Sorry, I answered after you edited the message. Let me try it out :)

Comment: Ok, I couldn't get that working, but I think I should be using *FilterStream* instead of *SampleStream*, because the second one its suposed just to deliver *a sample* of all tweets and I'd like to get them all, also that way I could save some traffic I guess (because SampleStream would fetch many tweets, filter them out and save the matching ones, but FilterStream would fetch many and save all those many.